# Chrome not reporting CSP violations

Tags: google-chrome, content-security-policy

For some reason, Chrome (or at least my Chrome) isn't reporting CSP violations. It correctly refuses to display prohibited content, but it doesn't report the violation. By way of comparison, Firefox reports the violation just fine.

[Consider this page](https://www.idocs.com/dev). Your browser should not display an image in that page, because that image is from a prohibited URL. Chrome does that part just fine. However, Chrome does not obey the report-to or report-uri directives (I have both). Again, Firefox obeys those directives.

I understand that a browser may choose not report redundant violations, but that's not the case here. [I've](https://www.idocs.com/dev?x=2) [tried](https://www.idocs.com/dev?x=3) [using](https://www.idocs.com/dev?x=4) [different](https://www.idocs.com/dev?x=5) [urls](https://www.idocs.com/dev?x=6) and none of them produce reports.

I'm using Chrome Version 75.0.3770.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on Chrome Version 76.0.3809.100. Also, according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/report-to) page Firefox does not support `report-to`, only `report-uri`, so my guess is that Firefox is just using that one. Chrome supports both, and only using `report-uri` does work for me in Chrome. When I add `report-to` though it stops working. I suspect that when using both, Chrome ignores `report-uri` and favors `report-to`, which apparently is buggy, resulting in it not doing anything at all.

Comment: As of Chrome 89 report-to still appears to be broken: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1098885

Answer (score 4):

You may listen 'securitypolicyviolation' event and report manually

```js
if(window.chrome /* and if not setting report-to using HTTP response headers */) {
  document.addEventListener('securitypolicyviolation', (e)=> {
    let reportToUrl='https://example.com/csp-reports'; // change it
    fetch(reportToUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/csp-report'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'csp-report':{
          'blocked-uri': e.blockedURI,
          'document-uri': e.documentURI,
          'original-policy': e.originalPolicy,
          'referrer': e.referrer,
          'script-sample': e.sample,
          'source-file': e.sourceFile,
          'violated-directive': e.violatedDirective
        }
      }),
      credentials: "omit",
      cache: "no-cache",
      referrerPolicy: "no-referrer"
    });
  });
}
```

**2023 update**

HTTP response headers below should work.

First:

```http
Report-To: {  "group": "csp-endpoint",
              "max_age": 5,
              "endpoints": [
                { "url": "https://example.com/csp-reports" }
              ] }
```

then

```http
Content-Security-Policy: report-to csp-endpoint;
```

or

```http
Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: report-to csp-endpoint;
```

Comment: Note: Some features, such as sending CSP violation reports, are only available when using the HTTP headers. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP#sect1